# MVC Razor get values from controller in a view for javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to get values from a controller method in a view to write into some javascript.  In web pages it is as simple as <%=functionName()%>.  Is there a way to do this in MVC.  I cannot use the model because the javascript has to be available on page load.  Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in MVC

Yes, of course.

> I cannot use the model because the javascript has to be available on page load.

Of course that you can use a view model, there's nothing that would prevent you from doing so. So you start by defining it:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

then have a controller action that will populate this view model and pass it the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Foo = "Hello World"; 
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally have a strongly typed view to this view model in which:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var foo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Foo));
        alert(foo);
    });
</script>
```

But now let's suppose that you don't want to pollute your view with javascript but have it in a separate js file instead (which of course is the correct way).

You could embed the value somewhere in your DOM, for example using HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<div id="foo" data-model="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(Json.Encode(Model)))">
    Click me to surprise you
</div>
```

and then in a separate javascript subscribe to the click event of this element and read the `data-*` attribute in which we have JSON serialized the entire view model:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        var model = $(this).data('model');
        alert(model.Foo);
    });
});
```